# Use nested functions as callbacks with Windows API functions?

Tags: function, winapi, callback, window, d

I have the following code, this works.

```
import core.sys.windows.windows: EnumWindows;
import std.stdio: writeln;

void*[] hWndList;

extern (Windows) int callback(void* hWnd, long /* lParams */ ) nothrow {
    hWndList ~= hWnd;

    return true;
}

void main() {
    EnumWindows(&callback, 0);

    writeln(hWndList);
}
```

I was hoping I could use something more akin to JavaScript's syntax: `(void* hWnd, long) => {}`.

I tried this but I'm getting errors with the signature, it says the function is a delegate and apparently Windows API can't accept a delegate.

```
import core.sys.windows.windows: EnumWindows;
import std.stdio: writeln;

void main() {
    void*[] hWndList;

    EnumWindows((void* hWnd, long /* lParams */ ) nothrow {
        hWndList ~= hWnd; return true;
    }, 0);

    writeln(hWndList);
}
```

I'm not going to even paste the compiler error because I am very clearly going about this the wrong way.

Of course there is nothing wrong with defining each callback as a separate function, but then comes the issue of naming them. I also don't like the way it makes my code look.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you try a nested static function. i can write more later, not sure if it allows extern(Windows) as a nested function but it might and then you can define on the line before the call and use it here

Comment: the callback must strictly comply with the expected signature. your nested (like c++ lamda) function does not match to this signature. because nested function really member function on some unnamed object and it have additional hidden parameter (like *this* ) - really how you access `hWndList` in your callback ? because pointer to this local variable saved in hidden local object on which you local callback. anyway you need static function as callback. possible on local object, but static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I can cast the delegate (or lambda) to the correct signature specified by the MSDN documentation for [`EnumWindowsProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633498(v=VS.85).aspx).

I also didn't realize that it was very bad practice to access the frame of the D program by implicitly using `hWndList` from the global scope.

This is what I used to create the correct signature.

```
alias EnumWindowsProc = extern (Windows) int function(HWND, LPARAM) nothrow;
```

Then I discovered that the alias already existed as `ENUMWINDOWSPROC` in the MinGW headers at `core.sys.windows.windows` at line 2483 (at the time of writing).

```
extern (Windows) nothrow {
    ...
    alias BOOL function(HWND, LPARAM) ENUMWINDOWSPROC;
    ...
}
```

To solve the issue of implicitly passing D's frame, I used `cast(LPARAM) &hWndList` as the `lParam` in [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows).

This became an issue of using the pointer now. I know this is probably botched, any suggestions welcome, but I casted it to a pointer.

```
*(cast(HWND[]*) lParam)
```

And the full code looks something like this. Obviously, this was just a minimal example to begin with, so you may want to assign the casted pointer to something so it's less confusing when using the variable from `lParams`.

```
import core.sys.windows.windows: EnumWindows, ENUMWINDOWSPROC;
import std.stdio: writeln;

void main() {
    HWND[] hWndList;

    EnumWindows(cast(ENUMWINDOWSPROC) (HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
        *(cast(HWND[]*) lParam) ~= hWnd;
        return true;
    }, cast(LPARAM) &hWndList);

    writeln(hWndList);
}
```

I hope this helps someone because this was confusing as hell for me (still not sure I understand the pointer logic).

Thanks to Boris-Barboris on the D Forums for giving me something to work from.

https://forum.dlang.org/post/xxklxaajptppockvazeo@forum.dlang.org

Comment: Are you compiling for 64 bit? Your code I am pretty sure it wrong on 32 bit - a C long and D's long are not actually compatible in general (and an LPARAM is really more of a `void*` than a long per se)

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Nope, this is 32-bit.

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely wrong then, it just happens to work for now because the 32 bit pointer will fit in the first few bytes of the long, but this is liable to lead to stack corruption later as the function tries to clean up 8 bytes, not realizing there are 12 actually there. You will want to change that long to a `c_long`, which is located in `import core.stdc.config;`, or to a `void*`

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Works fine with no argument, `-m32`, and `-m64`. It's a Windows function so I can't change to a `void` pointer anyway, I tried.

Comment: I just tried and your code does not even compile on 32 bit. (which is good, better than stack corruption!). Something must be weird with your setup, maybe the m32 is overridden by a global config somewhere. `cannot pass argument cast(long)& hWndList of type long to parameter int`.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe That `long` from [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) is an [`LPARAM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types#LPARAM), which is an alias for [`LONG_PTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types#LONG_PTR) which is just a regular `long`. I compiled two executables, one 64, the other 32, and checked them with `dumpbin /headers`. Both say they are the correct architecture. I don't know why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: LONG_PTR is *NOT* an alias for a regular `long`. It is an alias for a `long`... in C, which is different than a long in D. The `_PTR` in the Windows name gives a vital hint - it is sized to hold a pointer. What dmd version do you have? It might have buggy headers.